# How to find all occurrences of specific DLL in whole solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if there is possible to find all occurrences of a particular assembly referenced to in many projects in a large projects solution.

Visual Studio should natively support that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to do that is click right button on require assembly in solution explorer and choose option "Project Hierarchy" and eventually click refresh button in appeared dialog window...

Natively supported by VS. I like it :) !